# QField - get GPS Fix Status of captured point

Tags: qgis, gps, qfield

I have a GG04 Receiver from Leica, using it with Leica ZenoConnect, NTRIP and activated MockLocation in QField, antenna in QField is set to internal. The Receiver is connected via Bluetooth.
We have to get the GPS Fix Mode information from the receiver (RTK Fix, RTK Float, DGPS Fix, GPS FIX, Invalid). QGIS/QField has a variable named "@position_quality_description" (f.e. Fixed RTK), that seems to be the information I need. But after capturing a point this field is empty. When I use the variable "@position_fix_status_description" instead i get f.e. Fix3D. But I don´t have an idea how to evaluate this information.

Any suggestions how to get the GPS Fix Mode?